# Create alias with git like gits or gitxxx

Tags: git

I want to create alias with git so as to have someting like gitxxx:

for example, instead of :

```
git statut
```

I want

```
gits
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: do this in your shell?  what are you using?  `alias gits=git status` should do what you want (assuming a sh based shell).

Comment: If you're using aliases, take a look at Bash-it, it has a nice collection of Git aliases in addition to many other nice things: https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/master/aliases/available/git.aliases.bash Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of that project.

Comment: Using a bash alias instead of a git alias, just to avoid having to type a space between the 's' and the git command seems to me overkill! Use a git alias, it's easier to set up, maintain and located in your git profile file.

Answer (score 1):

alias of git can be create like this command

git config --global alias.co checkout

for further reference please check

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: This adds an alias for the command but still requires `git` to be prefixed; in this case `git co` instead of `git checkout`. It won't work for `gitco` in the question though.

Comment: Could you please read my question before send answers ? I want a particular alias like gitxxxx instead of git xxx

Answer (score 1):

you would need to use a shell alias

something like  `alias gits='git status'`

```
[projects/iadmin] gits                                      (git-svn)-[master]
zsh: command not found: gits
[projects/iadmin] alias gits='git status'                   (git-svn)-[master]
[projects/iadmin] gits                                      (git-svn)-[master]
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This assumes a *nix like environment and sh based shell.  But as others have pointed out, you cannot use internal git aliases as you would still need to prefix with git..

I also use shell functions for some of this.

from my zshrc

```
# No arguments: `git status`
# # With arguments: acts like `git`
g() {
  if [[ $# > 0 ]]; then
    git $@
  else
    git status
  fi
}
```